# Minimal Pinterest Widget with CSS

Tags: css, widget, pinterest

A while ago I had managed with very limited CSS knowledge to remove the user name; widget boarder; picture boarder; and 'follow on Pinterest' button. This was achieved by tagging the widget (in HTML) with:

```
div id="pinterest-container"
```

and then using the following CSS commands to hide everything but the pictures:

```
#pinterest-container > span { box-shadow: none !important; }
#pinterest-container > span > span > a { display: none; }

#pinterest-container span a:nth-child(3){
display: none !important;
}

.post-body center div#pinterest-container span span a{
display: block !important;
}

.post-body center div#pinterest-container span span span a{
display: block !important;
}
```

However a short time ago this stopped working and the picture boarders, user name and ffollow button all returned: http://www.andrewmacpherson.me/p/precedence.html

I would be very greateful if someone could help me hide these again, I've been searching and testing but with no luck!

Many thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember hiding things like this back in the Myspace days. Overriding certain elements was often a complicated and brittle process. Fortunately, we've now got CSS attribute selectors, providing a more elegant way to handle situations such as yours. The `$=` part of the following selectors are targeting `class` attribute values *ending with* those certain suffixes (`_img`, `_col`, etc.). Hopefully, these overrides will last a little longer than the last batch.

Remove picture and widget borders:

```
#pinterest-container [class$=_img] {
  display: block !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;  
}

#pinterest-container [class$=_col] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Kill the follow buttons:

```
#pinterest-container [class$=_button] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

To remove the scrollbars, you'll have to do something a bit more general. *Note: this will show all of the content in each group of images, so no truncation occurs.*

```
#pinterest-container span span {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect and educational! I also managed to target the 'user name' header and remove that. However, any idea how to remove the scroll bars?

Comment: @AndrewMacpherson I updated my answer to include a bit about removing the scrollbars.

Comment: Works a treat, greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: @AndrewMacpherson No problem. Can you up-vote/accept my answer?

Comment: Accepted the answer, apparently I need more reputation to up-vote it, which I shall do as soon as I can! Thanks again!