# Hide the scrollbars and the box shadow in pinterest widget

Tags: html, css, pinterest

I tried

```css
#pinterest-container [class$=_img] {
  display: block !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;  
}

#pinterest-container [class$=_col] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

from this post [Minimal Pinterest Widget with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310156/minimal-pinterest-widget-with-css) and a couple other posts but the border (box-shadow) doesn't budge. What can i do? Would changing the color work.

Also I need help with hiding the scroll bar **of the widget** (but still be able to scroll) on all browsers.

I tried this but it removes all scroll bars from the embedded page. I just want to remove the scrollbars of the widget only.

```css
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* Optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

I have limited knowledge on CSS  so please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Scrollbar

In your solution, you removed the scrolling option from all `html` elements, which is not what you need. Within the `iframe`, you need to find the element that has a scroll bar within the `pinterest widget`. This element is a `span`. Let's see how to distinguish it from other spans. It has a special attribute that I believe is only found in the pinterest widget: "data-pin-log."

[image: scrollbar in pinterest widget]

Using this, I removed the scroll bar exclusively from the `pinterest widget`:

```css
span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"]::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* Optional: show position indicator in red */
span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"]::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

[Show example in codepen](https://codepen.io/mastersystem321/pen/PoyzGoe)

### BoxShadow (?) --> maybe Border?

Without an example code, I don't know what `box-shadow` is being referred to. The widget has a visible `border` around it. I created an image of it and removed it using a similar method as above.

[image: border in pinterest widget]

Unfortunately, this removes the border from all Pinterest spans undesirably:

```css
span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] {
  border: none;
}
```

To precisely remove it only from the outer container, a more specific CSS selector is needed:

```css
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: I was able to remove the scroll bars but the border, still doesnt seem to go away. What if instead of border: none we just make it 0px? Would that work, or change the border color to just white? https://jpst.it/3bn7_ < heres the code ive used so far.

Comment: If you're using multiple widgets, then my `:first-child` approach won't work. Remove it and it should work! (Updated.) You can check the working code in the attached demo project on codepen.io.

Comment: i tried it but it still didn't work. how about we remove the white padding on the left, right and bottom from the widget here -> toastedmacarons.com. then the border wouldnt matter much.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mastersystem321/pen/PoyzGoe or https://stackoverflow.com/a/76300186/15167500 (short answer: `body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"]`)