# How do i get rid of the padding around the widget inside the border?

Tags: html, css, pinterest

[image]

The first image is what i have and the second is the result i want to accomplish.

[image]so far ive realised that disabling the two ticks (in the picture above) does the trick but how do write the css code?

Here's the code im currently using to adjust the widget to my liking.

```css
span[data-pin-log="pinterest"] {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"]::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* Optional: show position indicator in red */
span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"]::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}

#pinterest [class$=_button] {
  display: none !important;
}
#pinterest [class$=_button] {
  display: none !important;
}
#pinterest [class$=_hd] {
display: none !important;
}
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<a data-pin-do="embedBoard" data-pin-board-width="350" data-pin-scale-height="500" data-pin-scale-width="130" href="https://www.pinterest.co.uk/toastedmacarons/rich-boys-city-girls/"></a>
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

If it helps this widget is live on [here](https://toastedmacarons.com/).

I have very limited knowledge on CSS so any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance :))

Comment: Perhaps something like `body > span[data-pin-href="https://www.pinterest.com"] > span:nth-child(2) { padding: 10px; }`?

Comment: That didnt work

Comment: It works for the snippet in your question. How you adapt it depends on your *actual* HTML, a context that you did not provide.

Comment: how can i locate the actual HTML

Comment: Similar to how you accessed the CSS styles, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Follow my css code:

```css
/* Remove scrollbar */
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"]::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
}

/* Remove border */
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] {
  border: none;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

/* Remove padding */
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] {
  padding: 0;
}

/* Hide header (pinterest logo) */
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"]:first-child {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide follow button */
body > span[data-pin-log="embed_grid"] > span[data-pin-log="embed_user_ft"]:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

[Full example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/mastersystem321/pen/PoyzGoe)